# PHP MySQL import script not importing all rows

Tags: php, mysql, csv

for some reason my PHP CSV import script isn't working how it should, I need it to ignore the first line of my CSV and import all other rows into my table.

The issue I am having is that the script is only importing half of the rows in the CSV file, I'm guessing it's because of the IGNORE 1 LINES statement.

Here is my script:

```
<?php

$databasehost = "localhost"; 
$databasename = "name"; 
$databasetable = "import"; 
$databaseusername="username"; 
$databasepassword = "password"; 
$fieldseparator = ","; 
$lineseparator = "\n";
$enclosedbyquote = '"';
$csvfile = "db-core/feed/csv/test.csv";

if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
        $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
        array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        )
    );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}

$pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `$databasetable`");

    $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." REPLACE INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
    FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ".$pdo->quote($enclosedbyquote)."
     TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)." 
    LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)." 
    IGNORE 1 LINES");

echo "Loaded a total of $affectedRows records from this csv file.\n";

?>
```

How could I ignore the first row of the CSV file but include all the rows after?

EDIT: Here is one of the rows from the CSV:

```
"AETA83919","AETV34458584","SD57VUP","BLACK","Diesel","2007","76778","Hatchback","3","VAUXHALL","CORSA","1.3 CDTi [90] SXi 3dr [AC]","1200","3989","","Manual","http://images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA83919/AETV34458584_1b.jpg","0","3","","0","2007 57 reg VAUXHALL CORSA 1.3 CDTi [90] SXi 3dr [AC], Manual, Hatchback, Diesel, 76,778 miles. BLACK, Comprehensive Warranty Included In Price. HPI Checked! Pre Delivery Health Check!, 5 seats, LOVELY VAUXHALL CORSA SXI 1.3CDTI SXI WITH AIR CONDITIONING!! VERY WELL CARED FOR AND MAINTAINED AND JUST SERVICED BY DRIVEN CAR SALES LTD AT 76K!! GREAT COMBINATION OF PERFORMANCE AND ECONOMY!! VIEWING AND TEST DRIVING IS RECOMMENDED!! EACH CAR COMES WITH A MININIUM 9 MONTHS MOT. FULL MECHANICAL HEALTH CHECK GUARANTEES CAR IS PREPARED TO THE HIGHEST STANDARD. COMPREHENSIVE RAC WARRANTY INCLUDED. DRIVEN CAR SALES WELCOME ANY INSPECTION. BUY WITH CONFIDENCE AND REASSURANCE AS DRIVEN CAR SALES LTD ARE OFFICIAL MEMBERS OF RETAIL MOTOR INDUSTRY FEDERATION. VIEW OUR REVIEWS ON TRUSTPILOT. 3,989","","0","1","","UK","0","","0","0","","","",""
```

As you can see there is an extra quotation mark on the end of the row, this extra quotation mark appears on all of the rows.

I guess this is the issue and if so is there a way to work around this?

Any help would be great on this.

Comment: It is probably not due to the `IGNORE 1 LINES`.  Did you closely examine the last row imported? Make sure that something like a quoting error in the source CSV isn't causing all the remaining rows to be inserted as a column value of the last one successfully inserted.

Comment: Are you able to successfully import the whole CSV if you just run the `LOAD DATA` command manually? Does MySQL issue any warnings (`$pdo->query("SHOW WARNINGS")`

Comment: I have edited my post @MichaelBerkowski you were right about the last row, I hate to be cheeky but do you know how I could amend my script to cope with this problem or is it not possible?

Comment: I'm not seeing the extra quotation mark at the end of the sample row - I only see it as an empty string in whatever is the last column.  If you are in control of the data source that generated this CSV, it would be much much better to fix it at the export source than to try to work around it in your import.

Comment: What about the first line after the import stops. I would expect this one to be faulty.